# Mongoose, properties did not return enough when update

Tags: javascript, mongoose

my schema:

```
       ...
       var images = new Schema({
                name: String,
                poster: {
                  w: { type: Number, default: null },
                  h: { type: Number, default: null },
                  local: { type: String, default: null },
                  local2: { type: Object, default: null }
                }
        })
        ...
```

When I create `db.images.create({ name: 123 })` it returns:

```
    {
      _id: <something object>,
      name: 123,
      poster: {
        w: null,
        h: null,
        local: null,
        local2: null
      }
    }
```

it really good , but when I try update
`db.images.updateOne({ _id: <Object _id> }, { poster:{ w: 10 } })`
and it just returns:

```
    {
      _id: <something object>,
      name: 123,
      poster: {
        w: 10
      }
    }
```

I want block all field in poster , how can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **select({poster:0})** with **updateOne()** it will block poster to render after update .

Comment: i think you undertand my question.

Comment: I tried to understand your question ! the think which i understand is that you don't want to poster after update.

Comment: i want update poster with a object ex: { w: 10 } but old object in doc is { w: 8, h: 10 }
and it just auto update w and keep the value h

Comment: Actually the problem is you are using updateOne() which only returns a response object as true and 1 you should use findOneAndUpdate() to return response of currently updated object.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
db.images.updateOne({ _id: <id> }, { $set: { 'poster.w': 10 } })
```